# if 2 array are equally individual value check but print value only one time

Tags: php

I HAVE 2 table IN DATABASE

```
user=>1st col=>user_id=>[1,2,3],  2nd col=>user_name=>[a,b,c]


 image=>

1st col=>user_id=>[1,1,2,2,3],2nd col=>image_path=>[abc,sd,as,cd]
```

MY OUTPUT
i want to output like this

```
{ user_id=1
    user_name=a
    image_path=abc
               sd}

   { user_id=2
    user_name=b
    image_path=as
               cd} and so on....conti
```

i want userid only once means not repeated again of same user and all other detail print like above

Comment: all of the array 2 must be in array 1 in terms of values?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to `JOIN` your tables on the `user_id` column with `JOIN image ON user.user_id = image.user_id` and select the columns you need.

Then use `array_reduce` to collect all image pathes into an array of the specific row:

```
$final = array_reduce($sqlResult, function($result, $row){
        if (!array_key_exists($row['user_id'], $result) {
            $result[$row['user_id']] = $row;
            $result[$row['user_id']]['image_path'] = [$row['image_path']];
        } else {
            $result[$row['user_id']]['image_path'][] = $row['image_path'];
        }
        return $result;
    }, []);
```

The result will be your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can first merge you array by `array_merge()` like this,

```
$new_array = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
```

by this you will get array combination of both the arrays and then you need to make it unique by `array_unique()` method like this,

```
$final_array = array_unique($new_array);
```

I hope it helps.

> EDIT ::

Oh i am sorry i misunderstands.
@Philipp Maurer answer is correct. as `array_intersect()` method give you the common values from both the arrays. 
see the link [array-intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)